# Values from tuples named the same as user input in Python (Hard for me to explain, will update title if I can find a better way to express myself)

Tags: python

I am an extremely novice learner, I am taking a Python class to learn.  This question has nothing to do with the class, just with a project I am working on as I am going through the class (I am working on a simple game, using concepts that I learn in class to update, expand, and clean up my code.)

I am learning about Tuples, Lists, and Dictionaries at this time, and thought that simple tuples would clear up a lot of IF statements and streamline the code.  However, I cannot get it to work exactly how I would like it to work.

Basically I have a set of tuples for all of my classes (Note, these are training classifications, and not Python classes).  They have different numbers in them, and then I have a tuple with a list of the names of all of the classes.  At some point in the code, I ask for user input to determine a character's class.  I would like to be able to use that input so I can extract (Is the correct term splice?) values from the tuple, say I want to add whatever value is in the third position of the tuple to another value.  Right now I cannot get the user input associate with the tuple of the same name.  Is there a way to do this?

---

```
# Class list
Apprentice = (6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Warrior = (12, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0)
Paladin = (14, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1)
Barbarian = (12, 6, 0, 3, -1, -1, -1)
Blademaster = (10, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Assassin = (8, 0, 8, -2, 0, 0, 0)
Rogue = (8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Monk = (10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, -4)
Bard = (8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4)
Mage = (6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0)
Priest = (6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1)
Wizard = (4, -2, -2, -2, 6, 8, 0)
Scholar = (6, -1, -1, 0, 4, 4, 0)
Necromancer = (6, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, -5)
classList = ('Apprentice', 'Warrior', 'Priest', 'Mage', 'Wizard', 'Rogue', 'Bard', 'Paladin', 'Scholar', 'Necromancer', 'Barbarian', 'Blademaster', 'Assassin', 'Monk')
```

---

```
validClass = False
while validClass == False:
    charClass = raw_input('What type of training have you had (Class)? ')
    if charClass in classList:
        print ''
        validClass = True
    else:
        print 'That is not a valid class.'
```

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you want...

Comment: you want to print the values of `Necromancer = (6, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, -5)` if `charClass = "Necromancer"` for example?

Comment: I think you've just independently rediscovered why dictionaries are so handy. :^)

Comment: Basically, if someone types in "Warrior" when prompted for charClass, I want to be able to access the values in the Warrior tuple.  So that I can then add those values later in the code.

Comment: void - Yes, for the basics printing those values would be a start, adding them to other values later in the code is the end goal.  DSM - I am sorry I have not gotten to the dictionaries portion yet, as my internet is basically maxed out on usage, I cannot view the lecture videos until the TA puts up the low bandwidth versions.  The normal videos are 70-90MB for a 5 minute video, while the low bandwidth ones are a tenth of that, although not very great clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by accessing the global variable list, however I would suggest *not* doing it this way. A better way of doing it is to create a dictionary of classes as follows:

```
classes = {'Apprentice':Apprentice,'Warrior':Warrior, ...}
```

Then do something like

```
selected_class = None

while True:
    charClass = raw_input('What type of training have you had (Class)? ')
    if charClass in classes:
        selected_class = classes[charClass]
        break
    else:
        print 'That is not a valid class.'
```

Comment: Velox, you gave me the answer I need, I needed a new variable and a way to set it to dictionary name with the splice being the value of the input variable, if it makes more sense than how I say it ;)  Much help, and very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should use dict

```
my_class = dict(
Apprentice=(6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
Warrior=(12, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0),
Paladin=(14, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1),
Barbarian=(12, 6, 0, 3, -1, -1, -1),
Blademaster=(10, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0),
Assassin=(8, 0, 8, -2, 0, 0, 0),
Rogue=(8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0),
Monk=(10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, -4),
Bard=(8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4),
Mage=(6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0),
Priest=(6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1),
Wizard=(4, -2, -2, -2, 6, 8, 0),
Scholar=(6, -1, -1, 0, 4, 4, 0),
Necromancer=(6, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, -5),
)
while 1:
    try:
        val = my_class[raw_input('What type of training have you had (Class)? ')]
        break
    except KeyError:
        print 'That is not a valid class.'
```

Comment: Neat, I almost forgot about dict()'s keyword argument input.

Comment: Thank you sir, you have been a help.  Is there a reason to use dict() over the {} can they be used in each Python, and is one "more acceptable" than the other?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a dictionary but if it's an assignment and you're not allowed to use dicts you can do the following:

```
validClass = False
while validClass == False:
    charClass = raw_input('What type of training have you had (Class)? ')
    if charClass in classList:
        print eval(charClass)
        validClass = True
    else:
        print 'That is not a valid class.'
```

The `eval` function lets you run python code within itself. Again, it's better to use a dictionary.

Comment: Muchos gracias, mi amigo!  Many thanks!  I ended up going with a dictionary as was described in another answer, but I am very grateful for your solution as well, this is not an assignment, just a little thing I am playing with throughout the term (I had my original code from the first week, and at the end of the term I want to go back and see how much more efficient my new code is, and how much more I can do with it.)  I appreciate your time, and wish you a blessed day.

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to use a dictionary, but if you aren't allowed to do so, you could use the `vars()` function, which returns a dictionary of all the global values.

```
while validClass == False:
    try:
        vals = vars()[raw_input('What type of training have you had (Class)? ')]
    except KeyError:
        print 'That is not a valid class.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try storing each variable in a dictionary along with strings of the character's name instead of creating separate tuples. Right now it would be impossible to link your ClassList with the stats because the variable name of each class cannot be compared with string name of each class (you would have to compare a string to another string).

If you haven't worked with Dictionaries before, try learning. I think it would be really helpful in this scenario!

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm